# Change the background color with image reference using input range in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image and a input range slider on top of that and when I slide the slider I need to change the background of the body according to the color on the image. Is it possible to do this in javascript or do we need to go with another approach? This is the image I have. When I move the slider to the extreme left I need the background to be yellow as in the image and when I move it to the extreme right it should be green

[image: range]

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Please create fiddle for better understanding.

Comment: Yeah sure please wait

Comment: Actually what I am trying is to get the color code or color on which the slider is.

Comment: How many different colors do you want to be able to select?

Comment: All from the image you see above, the extreme left has yellow and  right has green

Comment: How could you get yellow, if you wanted the color the slider is on? It's never on yellow.

Comment: Guys I am just giving you example lets consider the image which i posted now if you can see left color is orange cum yellow so whatever the slider points in I need that color code.

Comment: Just like the color palate html color picker. got it now wait I am posting some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getPixelForImage(img){
  if(!img.getPixel){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        width, height;

    function update(){
      canvas.width = width = img.naturalWidth;
      canvas.height = height = img.naturalHeight;
      (width || height) && ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }

    img.addEventListener('load', update);
    update();
    Object.defineProperty(img, "getPixel", {
      value: function(x, y){
        if(x<0 || y<0 || x >= width || y >= height) return 0;
        var p = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
        //rgba-color-string
        return "rgba(" + p[0] + ", " + p[1] + ", " + p[2] + ", " + (p[3]/255) + ")";

        //uin32 argb-value to calc with
        //return p[3]<<24 | p[0]<<16 | p[1]<<8 | p[2];
      }
    });
  }
  return img;
}

getPixelForImage(someImage).getPixel(10, 10);

//or

getPixelForImage(someImage);
//...
someImage.getPixel(x, y);
//...
```

but you might run into CORS-issues